# How to disable generating the project all the time in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-debugging

I am just having a problem in my Visual Studio 2005. Every time I debug my code, the project is re-generated and it really takes too much time. For this reason I am looking a possibility to disable this option if possible. Can you please help me with this situation?

Comment: Why don't use something more new (and less buggy) like VS 2008 or 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the solution and select "Properties". There should be an entry "Configuration" (sorry, I'm using German VS, so it may be named differently). There you can check boxes that determine whether a project should be built or not.

Please note that this affects the overall build process, too. I've had situations where I wondered why changes wouldn't work until I noticed that I kept working with an old version because I unchecked the `Build` checkbox!